# React: efficient re-render of tables

Tags: reactjs, flask, render, flask-socketio

I have a react + flask website.
The frontend creates a socketio connection to the backend and after that the backend periodically sends data for the frontend to update.
The data is a single dictionary. On each update I have to update a table in the UI.

Here's a pseudo code:

```
function Table ({data}) {
    const [dataTable, setDataTable] = useState(data);
    
    useEffect(() => {setDataTable(data)}, [data]);
    
    const createTable = () => {...};
    
    return createTable();

}

const createSocket = () => {...}

function Main() {
    const [state, setState] = useState(null);
    const socket = useRef(null);
    
    socket.current = createSocket();
    socket.current.on('state-update', (msg) => {setState(msg)});
    
    
    return <Table data={state.tableData} />
}
```

The problem is that the table only changes are in 1 cell. But I still render the whole table. The render is quick enough but the whole UI becomes unresponsive when it's done. And when I get 20-30 cells updates in a short time the UI might become unresponsive for 2-3 seconds which is noticeable.

How should I go about rendering the table in a more efficient way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could extract the actual "table_row" functionality as a separate component and wrap it in `React.memo`. So each of the rows will be re-rendered only if the props that you are passing have changed.

Make sure that you passing only the primitive data as props and if in of passing any callback functions make sure to wrap those in `React.useCallback` in the first place.